# How make an array only selected input text values and send array via ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

i want to add values in array and want to send on click 
i want to store value in array only those user input text i have click not all values store in array.
when i store all value in array its tacking time to update 
so i want to update only those value on which user have click or change in usert input text

1. This is my html code. When I click in one input text then it shows only that value and then I click on another input text then it store first input text value and second input text value.

   2. Meaning, I want an array which can store input text value in an `array()` whenever I try to store value in array it shows undefined of array
   3. Now I want this array to send via ajax. How can I do this so that all array data goes via ajax
   4. I know array is a collection of similar datatype. So I want to store id in which all ids, reps_value of array store all reps_value and reps_percent of array store all reps_percent value
2. And I want to submit my form using submit button on click

this is not working on click using seralizeArray() its giving me all input values when i click only two user input text

```
 $(document).on('Click', '.submit_prescription,input', function (e) {

    var x = $(this).parent().find("input").serializeArray();

    var val[] = $(this).val();
    var g[] = $(this).attr("name");
    var id[] = $(this).attr("id");

    //i am trying to store data in an array i using each loop but its not working properly how to set this loop to sore in array
    /*   alert(g);
        alert(val);
        alert(id);
    */

    //            $.each(x, function(key, values) {
    //        console.log(key, values.value);
    //        alert(key, values.value);
    //    });
    //            }

    //   var val = $("input:id").val();
    // var val = $("input").val();

    var g = $(this).attr("name");
    //alert(g);
    if (g == 'reps_value') {
        // alert('reps_valwwue');
        var f = $(this).attr("id");
        var d = $(this).val();
        var g = $(this).attr("name");
        var data2 = "id=" + f + "&reps_value=" + d + "&type=" + g;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "prescriptionUpdate1",
            data: data2,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#message").html(data);
                $("p").addClass("alert alert-success");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                //                                //alert(err);
            }
        });

    } else {
        //     alert('reps_percentage');
        var f = $(this).attr("id");
        var d = $(this).val();
        //var  data : { reps_percent : d, id : f },
        var data2 = "id=" + f + "&reps_percent=" + d + "&type=" + g;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "prescriptionUpdate1",
            data: data2,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#message").html(data);
                $("p").addClass("alert alert-success");
            },
            error: function (err) {
                //alert(err);
            }
        });

    }

    });
============================================================

    public function prescriptionUpdateData1($data) {

        @$id = $data['id'];
        @$reps_percent = $data['reps_percent'];
        @$reps_value = $data['reps_value'];
        $type = $data['type'];


        if ($data['type'] == 'reps_value') {
            $result = $this - > db - > query("UPDATE dev_prescription SET `reps_value`= '".$reps_value.
                "'
                WHERE id = '".$id."'
                ");
            }
            else {
                $result = $this - > db - > query("UPDATE dev_prescription SET `reps_percent`= '".$reps_percent.
                    "'
                    WHERE id = '".$id."'
                    ");
                }

                if ($result) {
                    return TRUE;
                } else {
                    return $this - > db - > _error_message();
                }
            }





<td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F2F2F2" sdval="20" sdnum="1033;"> <font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000">
       <input style="width:90%" type="text" name="reps_value" id="<?php echo $location[2] ?>" value="<?php echo $location[0] ?>" class="" /> </font></td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F2F2F2" sdnum="1033;0;0.0%">
     <font face="Agency-Roman" size="1" color="#FF0000"> <input style="width:38px" type="text" name="reps_percent" id="<?php echo $location[2] ?>" value="<?php  echo $location[1] ?> "class="" /><input style="width:38px" type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $location[2] ?>" class="" /> </font>
     </td> <td align="left" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><font color="#000000"><br></font></td>
      <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F2F2F2" sdval="20" sdnum="1033;">
                    <font face="Agency-Roman" color="#000000">
                        <input style="width:90%" type="text" name="reps_value" id="<?php echo $location[5] ?>" value="<?php echo $location[3] ?>"
                            class="" />
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F2F2F2" sdnum="1033;0;0.0%">
                    <font face="Agency-Roman" size="1" color="#FF0000">
                        <input style="width:38px" type="text" name="reps_percent" id="<?php echo $location[5] ?>" value="<?php echo $location[4] ?>"
                            class="" />
                        <input style="width:38px" type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $location[5] ?>" class="" />
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td align="left" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <font color="#000000"><br></font>
                </td>
```

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting